# Unable to register css / js using assets / registerCss function

Tags: yii2, assetbundle

I had created a testasset.php as follows :

```
<?php

namespace app\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class TestAsset extends AssetBundle {
    /*public $basePath = '@webroot';
      public $baseUrl = '@web'; */
      public $sourcePath = '@app/assets';
      public $css = [
        '/css/test.css',
      ];
      public $js = [];
      public $depends = [
      /*  'yii\web\YiiAsset',
          'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset', */
      ];
}
```

In controller i am simply rendering view file which register above asset.

view :

```
<?php 

use app\assets\TestAsset;
TestAsset::register($this);
$this->beginPage(); ?>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Register JS and CSS</title> <?php 
     //Yii::$app->view->registerCssFile('/css/style.css');?>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/test.css" type="text/css" /> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page">
      <div id="logo">
        <h1><a href="/" id="logoLink">Register JS and CSS Test</a></h1>
      </div>
      <div id="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">!</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">@</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p> XYZ...!!! </p>
        <p> ABC...!!! </p>
      </div>
      <div id="footer"> 
        <p> Webpage made by <a href="/" target="_blank">XYZ</a> </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But my test.css file is not getting registered. 
I had tried using basepath and baseurl as well and registerCss Yii2 function but with no success.

Anyone Please suggest where i am lacking in my code.

Comment: view file generally does not have the `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>` tags as they are rendered through the layout file. Are you not using layouts?

Comment: I am using layout file in my main project. its just a test code that i have shared so does not have any separate layout file.

Comment: If you are not using layouts then you can try to render the header asset files explicitly as suggested in @Bizley's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
<?php $this->head() ?>
```

preferably somewhere between `<head>` and `</head>` for the `header` asset files to be rendered.

Comment: Sorry but this does not worked out, neither do adding $this->beginBody() and endBody in body tag worked.

Comment: Could you add rendered source code for this page? From the beginning to the `</head>` tag.

Comment: <html>
  <head>
    <![CDATA[YII-BLOCK-HEAD]]>    <title>Register JS and CSS</title>     <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/test.css" type="text/css" /> -->
  </head>

Comment: @user3350093 did you call `<?php $this->endPage() ?>` at the bottom of your view? Because the replacement of the placeholder `<![CDATA[YII-BLOCK-HEAD]]>` happens after the page rendering is completed.

Comment: No i was not using endPage(). Adding this to the bottom of view solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simply  add this in view file

```
<?php 
   $this->registerCssFile('PATH_TO_FILE');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks.. adding endpage at the bottom of my view works.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue on one of my advanced application template projects.
I've compared my layout/main.php file with the same on the [Yii2 advanced application template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/views/layouts/main.php) and found missing `$this->endPage()` at the end of file.
It was removed by mistake and without it no js, ccs assets worked.